# Connect to replica set using mgo

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo, replicaset

I'm using `mtools` to spin up a replica set with 3 nodes (`mlaunch --replicaset`) on ports 27017, 27018, and 27019.

However I'm having difficulty actually connecting to the replica set using `Dial` from the mgo package. The code snippet below panics with the message `no reachable servers`:

```
type Person struct {
    Name   string `bson:"name"`
    Age    int    `bson:"age"`
}

func main() {
    session, err := mgo.Dial("localhost:27017,localhost:27018,localhost:27019")
    if err != nil {
            panic(err)
    }
    c := session.DB("mydb").C("testCollection")
    c.Insert(&Person{Name: "Foo", Age: 20})
}
```

How exactly does one connect to a replica set using the mgo package?

Comment: Are you able to connect to the replica set via mongo --host localhost --port 27017?

Comment: what does the panic error says ?

Comment: @JohnPetrone, I am able to connect to the replica set and issuing that command brings me into the mongoDB shell. Is there further initialization/setup that I need to perform to get the set into a working and accessible state?

calling `rs.status()` from inside the shell gives
    `{
 "startupStatus" : 3,
 "info" : "run rs.initiate(...) if not yet done for the set",
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "can't get local.system.replset config from self or any seed (EMPTYCONFIG)"
    }`

Comment: As an aside, I ran into something similar when I was trying to initiate a Mongo cluster with Mgo recently.  Mgo by default will check to see if the node you are connecting to is the master.  In the case of an uninitialized cluster, you are not and it will wait and ultimately panic. If you provide the "mgo.DialInfo" and set the "direct" to true, Mgo will not perform this check and you then can initialize the replica set via Mgo prior to attempting the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run `rs.initiate()` to complete the initial replica set configuration. This will initiate a one member replica set. You then run `rs.add()` with the correct parameters for your hosts to bring the other members online.

Here's a tutorial on the process:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/

Generally a good idea that any time you are having issues with running something against mongodb from within code try to connect and do the same thing via the mongo shell - it can save you much time and effort.

To re-start this process using mlaunch you need to run it this way:

```
mlaunch --init --replicaset
```

This will initialize and launch a 3 node replica set named "replset"

Comment: When I create the replica set manually everything works as expected. I was still unable to successfully initiate the set after running `mlaunch --replicaset`. Calling `rs.initiate()` gives `{
 "info2" : "no configuration explicitly specified -- making one",
 "me" : "bdr:27017",
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "couldn't initiate : can't find self in the replset config"
}`.

Comment: I'd avoid mixing mlaunch and manual replica set commands - will update answer with how to do this via mlaunch.

Comment: I believe the issue was a conflict in naming. I am now able to issue `mlaunch --replicaset` and then enter the shell and create a config variable `config = { "_id" : "replset", "members" : [ { "_id" : 0, "host" : "localhost:27017"}, { "_id" : 1, "host" : "localhost:27018"}, { "_id" : 2, "host" : "localhost:27019" } ] }`. Calling `rs.initiate(config)` then works as expected and the Go code is able to connect to the set. The issue was that in the previous config variable I specified `"name" : set0`, so there were conflicts when I tried to initiate.

Comment: Would be interested to know why `mlaunch` does not automatically set up the configuration for me. May just be an issue with how I installed/set it up.